# Java-chess game, data exchange from GUI to other classes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm currently working on a chess project.

I've set up a working code from console, and im working on setting up a GUI with swing. Debugging my application, I saw that my main and my GUI runs in different threads, so I came to the following question.

**Is there a way to put my main thread to sleep while waiting for the user to click on a chess piece, then resume after the click?**

To contextualize, I have a 8x8 array of buttons (`board[i][j]`) and for each button I set up a custom action that saves `i` and `j` into 2 static variables I declared into my main. So that after the button is clicked, I send the coordinates of that button to my main code that operates on the "real" matrix of chess pieces calling methods for controls.

Is that the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to put my main thread to sleep while waiting for the user to click on a chess piece, then resume after the click?

It is the wrong way to think.  A GUI should be event driven, rather than working in an infinite loop waiting for input (or for main to get input).

But the problems are (usually) from trying to 'match up' a command line based app and an app. with a GUI.

I say that because it sounds like the command line based app. did not go to the trouble of creating data structures for a `ChessGameModel` that can be acted on by the players and potentially shared amongst different classes that might need to interact with it.  Classes like .. a command line based front end, *or* the various classes of a GUI, or a server that is running chess games between people over the net or..

Build the `ChessGameModel` and the rest will be a lot simpler.

Comment: I agree with you, but building a model won't necessarily make his life easier, its a good practice though, and he should learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What if when you click on a button you set a variable which is checked continually by your "main thread".

```
//In your GUIClass (GUI Thread)
btnInput1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          oProcess.setInput("Forward");
    }
});

//In your Process Class (Main Thread)
private String input; 

public void setInput(String input){
   this.input = input;
}

public void checkInput(){
   while(true){
     if(input.equals("")
     {
         //Do nothing
         Thread.Sleep(1); //Sleep so your loop doesn't use 100% of your processor
     } else {
       if(input.equals("Forward")
       {
          //Do the action
       }
     }
   }
}
```

But you need to share the instance of your process class with the GUI Thread so you can use the same variable.

(Sorry for my spelling)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is: Yes, but you shouldn't.

Putting a Thread to "sleep" is wasting CPU cycles. Instead you should strive to make the stuff you do on your main-thread after recieving input in a more "event-driven" way.

First off you should already have some class that contains the board. If you haven't: now's the time ;)

The next thing you want to do is to not make that class your GUI, because the GUI shouldn't be concerned with the gamelogic.

and then it's getting simple, assuming following GUI field:

```
private Board board = // your actual board;
// assuming Java 8 
button.addActionListener((event) -> {
     board.recieveAction(i, j);
});
```